# how to render several templates in the same place several times?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have several templates:

```
<template name='mamals'>
    <div id={{id}} class="mamals-container">
        {{> UI.contentBlock}}
    </div>
</template>
<template name='dog'>
    {{#mamals}}
        <div class="dog">
           <p>I'm a dog</p>
        </div>
    {{#mamals}}
</template>
<template name='cat'>
    {{#mamals}}
        <div class="cat">
           <p>I'm a cat</p>
        </div>
    {{#mamals}}
</template>
<template name='pig'>
    {{#mamals}}
        <div class="pig">
           <p>I'm a pig</p>
        </div>
    {{#mamals}}
</template>
```

so in the main page I have a  where user can drag and drop as many animal as they want into the farm. What I need to accomplish is every time a user drag an animal I would like to render that template and add it to farm (NO replacing, just add it). How may I implement this???

thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried that much yet because all I know to do is how to display "static" template. I read something about `ui.dynamic` but that doesn't help either because display any template but once and it doesn't accept an input from the user (js) :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Blaze you can render any template dynamically using JS http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_render